# Training and experimentation system for developing software interfacing with SAP ERP

Tags: sap-erp, s4hana

I am trying to find a good place to start for a potentially SAP related project.
Suppose I wanted to develop stand-alone software that could connect with an SAP ERP (S4/HANA) system and analyze material management and accounting data. What resources would I need to accomplish that? Where could I get an SDK/the proper training for this? How would I get a system to experiment on? I've tried Googling this question but there doesn't seem to be clear authoritative information on this and what I find also seems to be mostly about SAP Business One, which is a different product.

Insights would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance,
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use REST/OData to connect to ECC and Hana S/4.
Currently, SAP has around 800+ REST APIs for SD/MM/PP/FICO, and almost every quarter, new APIs are added to Hana S/4.

You can check all the available APIs @ https://api.sap.com/package/SAPS4HANACloud/all

You can check out the demo below if you want to view an application that provides similar functionalities.

https://demo.inoerp.com:8090

Select Hana SandBox. This is a single app that provides similar functionalities for Oracle, SAP, Dynamics etc.

If you need an API that is not yet published. You can also create your own APIs using ABAP

Regarding technology - You can use anything Java(Springboot/ADF), C# .net, node.js. You will be fine as long as you stay away from the SAP technology stack (i.e., ABAP and UI5 :-))

Comment: Wow, thanks, this is really helpful! I didn't realize SAP created good OData APIs for its own components but that's awesome! I was already terrified to have to deal with NW RFC SDK. Just one last thing though, is there an economic way to access a demo company S4/HANA system economically, like the IDES system you used to get for SAP training as an independent student?

And I actually like UI5 ;)

Comment: lol!!!, last I heard, UI5 was using jQuery...which feels like stone-age.
Though, it's way better than writing ABAP in a crappy ECC IDE.
After using Flutter, I have moved out of all JavaScript frameworks (except react, which is required for docusaurus). Anyway, regarding the Hana S/4 instance, it's not cheap. You can google it, but the cheapest would be USD 40+ per month.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'd really love to know where you found that $40 monthly service. The best I can find is https://www.ides24.net/ which offers instances for $99-$199 monthly. Not that bad all in all but I'd rather pay $40 in this economy ...

Comment: That's the most expensive. Hana S/4 is more expensive than ECC. So probably you can start with ECC, and when ready to test with S/4, you get an S/4 server. Contact https://erptraininguk.org/ guys. Tell them you were referred by erpExpert. They are not big, but the service is pretty good. Just go to that site and click on the chat